# Calculating explicit dual basis of general linear group

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, dual-spaces

So Im trying to explicitly calculate the dual basis for a given basis of $Gl(n, \mathbb{R})$ with $x = (x^i_j)$ and $det(x) \ne 0$. I think this should be rather easy but i cant get to a result that seems to fulfill the $\delta^i_j$ criteria.

My given basis is:
$(X_a)_x = x^i_ja^j_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_k}$ with $a = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} \\
  \end{array}\right]$
and $\alpha= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right]$ , $\beta = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right]$, $\gamma= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 \\
  \end{array}\right]$, $\delta= \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right]\\$.

With this we define our basis as: $x_\alpha = x^i_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_1},x_\beta = x^i_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_1},x_\gamma = x^i_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_2},x_\delta = x^i_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i_2}$.

I now want to find the dual basis $\Theta^k$ with $k = [\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta]$ so that $<\Theta^{k}, X_{i}> = \delta^k_i$ for $i,k = [\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta]$.

If somebody could even just point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your vector fields are left-invariant, and so the dual basis should be as well. What is the dual basis to $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\mathfrak{gl}(n)$?

Comment: I mean i suppose theyre 1-forms of some kind, right? However Im not quite sure how finding the dual basis for matrices works... is it just taking the transposed inverse?

Comment: Forget matrices. You have (global) local coordinates.

Comment: I think youre trying to get me to the point of realising that $\Theta^{\alpha} = \Theta^i_j dx^j_i$ is that correct? In that sense would the dual basis for $\alpha$ and so forth just be $d\alpha$? I feel like I lack some understanding of the concepts on a very fundamental level, sorry for that.

Comment: Hint: At the identity element, what are $dx^i_j(\alpha)$, etc.?

Comment: $dx^i_1$ and so forth? If thats correct I can see how the scalar product over same indices works out to 1 with the right choice of constants, but how do I get to 0 with the others? Or does that just work out cause of the $dx^i_j$ and the partial derivatives having different indices? Again, I apologize if Im asking stupid questions!

Comment: Ive figured out where I got stuck at, I forgot that the scalar product in this case is defined via the interior product.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what *dual* means. This is not a scalar product. This is the pairing of an element of $V^*$ with an element of $V$. In particular, if $V=T_pM$ and $V^*=T^*_pM$, then for $\Theta\in V^*$ and $v\in V$, the pairing is of course $\Theta(v)$, which I suppose you can write as $\iota_v\Theta$. I think you need to go back and learn basics.

Comment: 100% agree, thank you very much for the help anyways!